# Draggable views weights not applied?

Tags: views

I have hard time setting up a DraggableViews (DV) view to re-order content. The DV actually **does** save the weights - they appear correct in the draggable table, but on the user side (when viewed on the site page) the weights are all zero (not retrieved?).

The site is bi-lingual and the content is tagged with a vocabulary. The purpose of the DV is to set the order within a term. In the header there's an exposed filter to allow the admin set the correct sequence within a term.

To my eyes, the query run to generate visitor's view is correct, but I'm not an expert.

Please refer to the attached mockup image to get an idea what's going on.
[image: Mockup screen]

I have the latest version of DV + Views 3.5.

Has anyone been through this? Does this have a known workaround? Is this module limitation or is it the view set up incorrectly?

**Edit:**

**User-facing View:**

```
SELECT draggableviews_structure.parent AS draggableviews_structure_parent, node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.language AS node_language, draggableviews_structure.weight AS draggableviews_structure_weight
FROM 
{node} node
LEFT JOIN {draggableviews_structure} draggableviews_structure ON node.nid = draggableviews_structure.entity_id AND draggableviews_structure.view_name = 'project_reorder' AND draggableviews_structure.view_display = 'page' AND draggableviews_structure.args = '[]'
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('project')) AND (node.language IN  ('en')) ))
ORDER BY draggableviews_structure_weight ASC
```

**Sorting UI View**

```
SELECT draggableviews_structure.parent AS draggableviews_structure_parent, node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.language AS node_language, draggableviews_structure.weight AS draggableviews_structure_weight
FROM 
{node} node
INNER JOIN {field_data_field_genre} field_data_field_genre ON node.nid = field_data_field_genre.entity_id AND (field_data_field_genre.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_field_genre.deleted = '0')
LEFT JOIN {draggableviews_structure} draggableviews_structure ON node.nid = draggableviews_structure.entity_id AND draggableviews_structure.view_name = 'project_reorder' AND draggableviews_structure.view_display = 'page' AND draggableviews_structure.args = '{\"field_genre_tid_i18n\":\"1\",\"language\":\"en\"}'
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('project')) AND (node.language IN  ('en')) AND (field_data_field_genre.field_genre_tid = '1') ))
ORDER BY draggableviews_structure_weight ASC
```

Note that the sorting view makes use of arguments (derived from exposed filter), while the user-facing one does not. I would think this might case the problem.

Comment: If this helps: below are the two queries pasted from Views

Comment: Is this custom built theme ?

Comment: To a certain extent - yes.

Answer (score 1):

Solution from [Chris](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/17865/chris) ([original post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/98952/draggable-views-module-doesnt-sort-content/108299#108299)):

**It worked to me.**

"
Only solution that worked for me was the following:

- go to your content type/vocabulary
- add a weight field (label: weight | machine name: weight | field type: integer
- edit your sorting view and add sort criteria for your newly added weight field
- edit your draggable views field and change "Handler" from Native to FieldAPI
- under Field select your weight field 
  -go to your content view and add the new weight field as you sort criteria

This is the only thing that worked for me. If it doesn't work immediately, just reorder a few items on your draggable view so that the ordering values are reset.

Hope this works for you too.
"

Comment: This method works for me (for case with several languages) but with an addition: I added a 'Synchronize translations' option for newly added field. This option is located on content type editing form.

Comment: There is no way. One more regression of Drupal 8 compared to Drupal 7!