# Draggable views module doesn't sort content

Tags: views

I wanna sort my view with Draggable Views Module , but my view display content not field.
is there any solution to sort my views ?

Comment: it's possible with Weight module if you sort it with Weight and remove all sorting option like post date ...

Answer (score 3):

Only solution that worked for me was the following:

- go to your content type/vocabulary
- add a weight field (label: weight | machine name: weight | field type: integer
- edit your sorting view and add sort criteria for your newly added weight field
- edit your draggable views field and change "Handler" from Native to FieldAPI
- under Field select your weight field
- go to your content view and add the new weight field as you sort criteria

This is the only thing that worked for me. If it doesn't work immediately, just reorder a few items on your draggable view so that the ordering values are reset.

Hope this works for you too.

Comment: Thx 
this is gonna work

Answer (score -2):

http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/custom-sort-drupal-content-draggable-views-module

see this I think its may be helpful..

Comment: Link answers aren't particularly helpful as they are unreliable and may be removed at any point. Perhaps you could summarise the post here in your answer?